# Не приходят данные Node.js ошибка 404

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Есть форма

```html
    <form action="/index" method="post">
        <div class="dws-input">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите логин">
        </div>
        <div class="dws-input">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
        </div>
        <div class="down">
            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberLoginAccount"><span style="margin-left: 10px" ><font style="color: white">Запомнить</font></span>  <br> <br>
            <input class="dws-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="ВОЙТИ" >
        <a href="#" style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="" >Восстановить пароль</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

В app.js

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
// view engine setup

var app = require('express')(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Обратите внимание на используемый путь. Именно он задается в атрибуте action формы
app.use('/index', bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
// Обратите внимание на используемый путь. Именно он задается в атрибуте action формы
app.post('/index', function(req, res, next) {
  // Объект req.body содержит данные из переданной формы
  console.dir(req.body);
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

В итоге кидает на страничку localhost:63342/index 
а в консоле это:

```html
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё просто, не был запущен сам node.js сервер.